# How to find indexes of array with value = 0? Java

Tags: java

Is there any way to find indexes of 0's in my array?

Im a newbie, so i dont know much.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter Array Size - ");
            int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();
    
            int[] array = new int[arraySize];
            int a = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                array[i] = a + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            }
    
int numberOfZeros = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            if (array[i] == 0) {
                numberOfZeros++;
            }
        }
        if (numberOfZeros == 0) {
            System.out.print("No Zero's in Array!");
        } else if (numberOfZeros > 0) {
            System.out.print("Number of Zero's in Array - " + numberOfZeros);
        }
```

Comment: You already found indexes of Zeros in your for loop with the check `if (array[i] == 0)`. All you need to do is save the found index `i` in some data struture like a Collection or Array in that if block

Comment: Can you put some effort to code formatting so that it is comfortable to read?

Answer (score 0):

Just print (or do whatever you need to do with it) index `i`. You already found zeros:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 0) {
        numberOfZeros++;
        System.out.print("The value zero is at index: " + i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the array , and each time you encounter a zero you can stock the index :

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Array Size - ");
        int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();

        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        int a = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = a + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<arraySize;i++) {
           if ( array[i] == 0 ) {
               System.out.println(" There is a zero on the index "+i );
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track the indexes using ArrayList and print it when you find zeros

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Array Size - ");
        int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();

        int[] array = new int[arraySize];
        int a = -1;
        int numberOfZeros = 0;
        List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = a + (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            if (array[i] == 0) {
                numberOfZeros++;
                indexes.add(i);
            }
        }

        if (numberOfZeros == 0) {
            System.out.print("No Zero's in Array!");
        } else if (numberOfZeros > 0) {
            System.out.print("Number of Zero's in Array - " + numberOfZeros + " , in positions: " + indexes);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are already looping thru the array and counting them, just add them to a `List<Integer>` for future reference.

However, if you need to find them in isolation of other code you can do it this way.

```
int[] vals = { 1,2, 0,20,33,2, 0, 99,9,10,0,4};
int[] zeroIndices = IntStream.range(0,vals.length)
          .filter(i->vals[i] == 0)
          .toArray();

System.out.println(zeroIndices.length + " zeroes found!");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(zeroIndices));
```

Prints

```
3 zeroes found!
[2, 6, 10]
```